# Slice numpy array wth list of wanted rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a numpy 2d array `A`, and a list of row numbers `row_set`. How can I get new array `B` such as if `row_set = [0, 2, 5]`, then `B = [A_row[0], A_row[2], A_row[5]]`?

I thought of something like this:

```
def slice_matrix(A, row_set):
    slice = array([row for row in A if row_num in row_set])
```

but I don't have any idea, how can I get a row_num.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `take()`:

```
In [87]: m = np.random.random((6, 2))

In [88]: m
Out[88]: 
array([[ 0.6641412 ,  0.31556053],
       [ 0.11480163,  0.00143887],
       [ 0.4677745 ,  0.43055324],
       [ 0.49749099,  0.15678506],
       [ 0.48024596,  0.65701218],
       [ 0.48952677,  0.97089177]])

In [89]: m.take([0, 2, 5], axis=0)
Out[89]: 
array([[ 0.6641412 ,  0.31556053],
       [ 0.4677745 ,  0.43055324],
       [ 0.48952677,  0.97089177]])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass a list or an array as indexes to any np array.

```
>>> r = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5))
>>> r
array([[3, 8, 9, 8, 4],
       [4, 1, 5, 9, 1],
       [3, 6, 8, 8, 0],
       [5, 1, 7, 6, 1],
       [6, 1, 7, 7, 7]])
>>> idx = [0,3,1]
>>> r[idx]
array([[3, 8, 9, 8, 4],
       [5, 1, 7, 6, 1],
       [4, 1, 5, 9, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Speed comparison: `take()` is faster.

```
In [1]:  m = np.random.random((1000, 2))
         i = np.random.randint(1000, size=500)

         %timeit m[i]
Out[1]:
         10000 loops, best of 3: 27.2 µs per loop

In [2]:  %timeit m.take(i, axis=0)
Out[2]:
         100000 loops, best of 3: 7.24 µs per loop
```

This remains true for very large `m` and `i`